# How do I send multiple responses?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When executing a query, I get records. But when  run the query again, these records will be duplicated.

Example:

request 1:

```
3424,DFS,21.07.2020 10:23
21312,123,21.07.2020 15:16
43324,RWR,22.07.2020 15:04
```

reques 2:

```
3424,DFS,21.07.2020 10:23
21312,123,21.07.2020 15:16
43324,RWR,22.07.2020 15:04
3424,DFS,21.07.2020 10:23
21312,123,21.07.2020 15:16
43324,RWR,22.07.2020 15:04
```

etc.

How to fix it?

```
const output = [];

module.exports.getAll = async function (req, res) {
    try {
        const cards = await Card.find({}, { NCard: 1, FIO: 1, AuthDate: 1 })
        cards.forEach((d) => {
            const row = [];
            row.push(d.NCard);
            row.push(d.FIO);
            row.push(moment(d.AuthDate).format('DD.MM.YYYY HH:mm'));
            output.push(row.join());
        });
        res.status(200).send(output.join(os.EOL))
    } catch (e) {
        errorHandler(res, e)
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that its the queryie's fault and not you not overriding the array on the frontend? If not, its probably an error inside `Card.find(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each call to `getAll` you add the result to `output`. So `output` grows with each call.

A first idea would be to move `const output = []` into your function.

Answer (score 0):

As output is defined above the scope of the function, it will store the result of the previous iteration and so on the next iteration output array will be containing the result of previous iteration. So You should move your output array inside your function.